# How to raise an exception when a string isn't comma-separated

Tags: python, string

I want it to raise an exception and print `Invalid input` if the input string is not separated by commas. However, this is not raising an exception.

```py
try:
    strings = [x for x in input().split(", ")]

except Exception:
    print("Invalid input.")
```

How can I raise an exception if the separator (i.e. comma) isn't present in the string?

Comment: You do realize that *any* string is comma-separated? If there are no commas, it just means there was one element. If you want your program to no accept certain strings, you have to be more specific about which characteristics you want the input to have.

Answer (score 2):

`split()` will return a list containing the original string if the delimiter doesn't appear in the list.

You can check the length of the resulting list -- if there's only one string, then the delimiter wasn't present in the original string, and you can raise an exception yourself:

```py
strings = input().split(", ")
if len(strings) == 1:
    raise ValueError("Invalid input.")
```

<sub>I also got rid of the list comprehension in the assignment to `strings` -- `.split()` already returns a list, so it isn't necessary.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Following code while check if all the words in the string are comma separated

```
import re

def check_comma_sepration(text_string):
    #Check if all the words in the string are seperated by comma
    word_count = len(re.findall(r'\w+', text_string))
    comma_sep_count = len(text_string.split(","))

    if word_count == comma_sep_count:
        print("Input string is comma separated ")
    else:
        print("Invalid input.")

# +ve test case
case1 = "Hi,this,is,case,one"
print("Case 1:")
check_comma_sepration(case1)
print()

# -ve test case
case2 = "Hi,this is case two"
print("Case 2:")
check_comma_sepration(case2)

# Output :
#     Case 1:
#     Input string is comma separated

#     Case 2:
#     Invalid input.
```

Comment: As said in a previous answer : "Raising an error is better than just printing, since the question specifically asks how to raise exception." Moreover, the use of regex is not necessary here and not fully explained

Comment: Well regex is used to count the actual number of words in the input string and compared it with the splits given by the "split" function. As you can see in the case 2 there is comma present in the string but the split function will not give you the word split which can be achieved by using regex. And about the exceptions, an custom or user defined exception need to be created in order to raise a exception.

Comment: I know what regex does, but my point is you didn't clearly explain it in your answer. Regex is not commonly used and Python can be used by beginner, so some explanation is a most for a good answer. Second point about raising exception, is you don't answer the question

Answer (score -2):

There isn't any exceptional behavior in your code since (at least as what you expected) since `split()` works just fine even if your delimiter is not found in the given string. It will just return the original string.

If all you want is to print a message if the input is not valid (i.e. not comma delimited), you can just check the `split()`'s return value:

```py
strings = input().split(", ")
if len(strings) == 1:
    print("Invalid input.")
```

Comment: Raising an error is better than just printing, since the question specifically asks how to raise exception.